# Parsing data in/ Creating dynamic component angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am trying to parse data in from one component to another.

Basically , I created 2 components.  My intention is to create a dynamic component where it can be used by back-end developer where it can place the code at its desired place with:

```
<fl-comtestCom [config]="_messageConfig" >
    Please <strong><b>remember</b></strong> that you are using ng-content as 
there is <b>no input</b> in description
</fl-comtestCom> `
```

But of course there should be some logic and configuration to be made.

This is how the logic should work....

If there is an input in description(see in the code below at description:"error"), it will display error, else it will read whatever is inside `fl-comtestCom [config]="_messageConfig`......

```
import { Component , OnInit , Input } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  selector: 'fl-comtest',
template: `

<fl-comtestCom [config]="_messageConfig" >
        Please <strong><b>remember</b></strong> that you are using ng-content as there is <b>no input</b> in description
</fl-comtestCom> ` 
})
export class FLComptest implements OnInit{

  private _messageConfig: any = {

    description:"Error",
  };
}
```

My if-else statement is declared here ....
If my description is undefined (false) it will return whatever is inside `fl-comtestcom>`, else if it not undefined (true). It should display error.

I am not sure how should I write the syntax. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import { Component , OnInit , Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'fl-comtestCom',
 template: `

 <template #ngContent> 
    <ng-content></ng-content> 
 </template>

 ` 
})

export class FLTestComponent implements OnInit{

  private _message: any = {};

  private _default: string = {description : ""};
  @Input() config: string;  


  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.config);

     if(typeof this.config.description == "undefined") {
        this.description
     }
     else (this.config.description != "undefined") {
        this.description;
     }

  }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you want to display different content depending on some condition. So i would do it like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fl-comtestCom',
  template: `
      <ng-content *ngIf="!config?.description"></ng-content>
      <div *ngIf="config?.description" [outerHTML]="config?.description"></div>
    `
})
export class FLTestComponent {
  @Input() config: string;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
<fl-comtestCom [config]="config" >
   Please <strong><b>remember</b></strong> that you are using ng-content as ....
</fl-comtestCom>
```

if you want to display custom error.

Or don't pass `config`(or remove `description` property from `config`) and it will display light DOM

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kDMD1FuuuTx3QFGpfsKs?p=preview)**